# Validating a link has been checked for registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a Terms and Conditions checkmark with the polices linked on the title of the checkbox.

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckIAgree" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="" CssClass="pull-left checkbox" ValidationGroup="Security" />
    <span class="termsconditions">I have read and agree to the site <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkTermsandConditions" CausesValidation="false" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="onclick_TermsandConditions" Text="Terms and Conditions" />.</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

On the onclick event I set a boolean value to 'true' to indicate that they have clicked the link.

```
//Make sure link has been clicked
protected void onclick_TermsandConditions(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    termsClicked = true;
}
```

I do declare the variable at the top of the page, which I think might be causing my problem because the page reload when I click the Terms and Conditions link.

```
bool termsClicked = false;
```

I do have a custom validator that makes sure the checkbox is selected, and then checks the value of the 'termsClicked' variable.  The 'termsClicked' variable always shows up false.

```
//Validate Terms
protected void cvValidateTerms(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = ckIAgree.Checked;
    if (termsClicked == false)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        cvTermsConditions.ErrorMessage = "You must view the terms and conditions";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: Why do you store the checkbox value? Do you have AutoPostBack set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

termsClicked is only true when you show them the terms and conditions.  It is not true when they post back the check mark (even if they previously read your terms/conditions).  You'll have to use the session or some other persistent state mechanism (maybe the ViewState) to remember that they clicked the link in some previous request/response.

Comment: Thanks I used the session, thanks for heading me down that track.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that, your variable declared globally or not?.

dont declare variable in the page load event.

Comment: the scope of his variable doesn't matter.  What matters is the page life cycle.